# Internal Link Broken While Using Jquery .show() .hide()

Tags: jquery, html, css

On my homepage I have a link to another page's internal link:

Homepage:

```
<a href="GetInvolved.html#sendacamper">Send a Camper</a>
```

Get Involved Page:

```
<section id="sendacamper" name="sendacamper">
Section Stuff Here
</section>
```

However, on the Get Involved Page I am running the following script to hide/show a certain div when you click different buttons:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#camper-container').hide();
$('.btn-group button').click(function(){
    var target = "#" + $(this).data("target");
    $(".dates-container").not(target).hide();
    $(target).fadeIn("slow");
});
});
</script>
```

So, whenever I manually load the page, GetInvolved.html#sendacamper it goes to the correct location. But when I click the homepage's link, it does not go to the correct spot. I am guessing this is so because the anchor loads before the script, and when the script hides the div above the anchor location is not correct.

Anybody got a possible workaround/fix?

http://campjoycem.businesscatalyst.com/index.html

The only way I can get it to work is to place the script in the head instead of the footer. But that is generally not acceptable because of page load times.

Comment: Its probably because you click on your button, which runs your function, but also goes to a different page, where it doesn't run the function. You probably want to run the function on page load?

Comment: It works perfectly fine for me (Chrome 43). What browser are you using?

Comment: Firefox 39 @TotempaaltJ

Comment: @putvande, you have it backwards. I click on the link on the page which doesn't run the function to go to the page where it is running the function. Also, I think it is running on page load since it initially hides the div and does so before any button is clicked, right?

Comment: Gotcha. From what I can tell, the #sendacamper never works if you're going there directly. If you go to GetInvolved.html, let it load, and *then* append #sendacamper to the URL (and press enter) it'll send you to the correct location only because it has already loaded the page and it doesn't reload the page on a simple hash change... That doesn't help much though.

Comment: @TotempaaltJ I just tried Chrome, and it's working as you said. Still doesn't work with Firefox.